Pick the price of plain bond off Hull-White Tree
Since we can use Hull-White tree to calculate the price of a option embedded bond, which can be achieved by the QuantLib pricing engine TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine, can this engine be also used to calculate the plain bond price, therefore we can calculate the option price by deducting callable bond npv from plain bond npv?

Not directly.  However, you can instantiate another callable bond with an empty callability schedule and use TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine.  This will give you the value of the plain bond.

Thank you very much, Luigi! But why can't the DiscountingBondEngine pricing engine be used to calculate the plain bond value according to the definition of plain bond (which is a plain bond is a bond without any option embedded)?

You can also use DiscountingBondEngine.  Using TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine for both callable and plain bond might cancel out numerical errors, since they're likely to be systematic. But they're probably negligible anyway.

Hi, @Luigi ~, I've tried set an empty callability schedule by just give an empty datelist to 'ql.CallabilitySchedule()' to append, but the 'CallableFixedRateBond' function returns aan error of in method 'new_CallableFixedRateBond', argument 9 of type 'std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &'. so, how can I build an empty callability schedule for a 'CallableFixedRateBond' ?

Either use ql.CallabilitySchedule() and don't append anything, or just pass an empty list [] to the constructor of ql.CallableFixedRateBond where the callability schedule is expected.

Neither works and still get the errorTypeError: in method 'new_CallableFixedRateBond', argument 9 of type 'std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &'...maybe it should work in C++?

Both work in Python.  May you post the code you're running?

callability_schedule = ql.CallabilitySchedule()
callable_bond = ql.CallableFixedRateBond(settlement_days, face_amount, schedule, coupons, day_count, ql.Following, face_amount, issue_date, calendar, callability_schedule)
The code on the CallableFixedRateBond setting is as above, and the error it brought is:
*TypeError: in method 'new_CallableFixedRateBond', argument 9 of type 'std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &'

I am so sorry for not assigning well the display format of the code, I don't know how to do the format setting...Apologies to you, Luigi

Ok, I see.  It's expecting the callability schedule as argument 9, but you're passing the calendar as 9 and the callability schedule as 9.  Remove the calendar, it's not in the signature of the constructor.

Thank you Luigi, as you mentioned, the difference is very negligible comparing with the DiscountingBondEngine

Hi, Luigi~ I am still wondering why the plain bond price evaluated by the method of simple discounting by spot rate is very similar to the price picked from a tree model... Doesn't the volatility and mean reversion speed set in the tree influence the shape of the term structure, and make the discount interest rate be different from the original? How come the difference between the two methods is so negligible?

Hull-White is calibrated to provide an exact fit to today's term structures. With other models, the difference would be larger.

Ok, I see, so both methods are using almost the same term structure!! THANK YOU, Luigi~!
